# pandas how to convert all the string value to float

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert all the `string` value in `Pandas DataFrame` into `float`, and I can define a short function to do this, but it's not a Pythonic way to do that. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]))
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
>>> df.dtypes
0    object
1    object
2    object
dtype: object
>>> type(df[0][0])
<type 'str'>
```

I just wonder whether are there some built-in functions of `Pandas DataFrame` to convert all the `string` value to `float`. If you know the built-in function on the Pandas doc, please post the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming all values can be correctly converted to float, you can use [`DataFrame.astype()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) function to convert the type of complete dataframe to float. Example -

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

Demo -

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]))

In [6]: df.astype(float)
Out[6]:
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [7]: df = df.astype(float)

In [8]: df.dtypes
Out[8]:
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
dtype: object
```

`.astype()` function also has a `raise_on_error` argument (which defaults to True) which you can set to `False` to make it ignore errors . In such cases, the original value is used in the DataFrame -

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'],['blah','bloh','bleh']])

In [11]: df.astype(float,raise_on_error=False)
Out[11]:
      0     1     2
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
2  blah  bloh  bleh
```

---

To convert just a series/column to float, again assuming all values can be converted, you can use `[Series.astype()][2]` . Example -

```
df['somecol'] = df['somecol'].astype(<type>)
```

Comment: Since the version 0.20.0 `raise_on_error` was replaced by `errors`

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use [`df.convert_objects(numeric=True)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html). It attempts to
convert numeric strings to numbers, with unconvertible values becoming NaN:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', 'foo'], ['bar', 'baz', 'quux']])
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
print(df)
```

yields

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5 NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
```

In contrast, `df.astype(float)` would raise `ValueError: could not convert string to float: quux` since in the above DataFrame some strings (such as `'quux'`) is not numeric.

Note: in future versions of pandas (after 0.16.2) the function argument will be `numeric=True` instead of `convert_numeric=True`.